# Get OneSignal player id in a page of a website that has been converted to app

Tags: javascript, android, onesignal

Sorry if my question has been answered in the past but I couldn't get into a solution for my problem.
I run the following script on the head section of my website to get the player id of One Signal.
It works fine when executed from a browser.
However when my site is executed through the andoid application it returns an empty field for the player id.

```
            var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];
            OneSignal.push(["init", {
              appId: "2c1ea700-16b5-43d7-a40d-40efsde6c90fdc",
            }]);
                            
            OneSignal.push(function() {
              OneSignal.getUserId(function(userid){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax/ajax_update_player_id.php",
                    data: {userid:userid}
                });     
              });
            });
```

Any help would be welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.
The developer of the mobile wrapper application includes the player_id on the url the first time the app is loaded so it was pretty easy to get it that way